# Rails - Upload and Add Several Records at One Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am currently using jQuery File Upload to upload multiple image files at once, whereby it is also adding these files to the model.

I am using the PaperClip, AWS, and s3_direct_upload gems to upload the images. I am following this tutorial here: http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

Here is what my model looks like: https://gist.github.com/dodinas/7237377

The problem I am running into, however, is that if I upload 15 images at once, only 8 or 9 get uploaded to S3 and added to the database.

I am not sure if the problem is with jQuery upload, S3, or my model?  Do I need to throttle the speed at which files are uploaded?

Any help would be great!

Comment: It would be good to know some more about the environment you're running on -- is it heroku? My initial thoughts are that perhaps your server's processes are throttling the uploads because of lack of resources or bandwidth?

Comment: Hi @RichPeck: I am using heroku.  However, the same issue also occurs in my local development environment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.  Turns out, I had some Javascript that was causing the page to redirect prematurely, not allowing the records to be added to the database.  I had something like:

```
$(document).bind("s3_uploads_complete", function() {
       window.location.replace("/choices");
});
```

I removed the javascript, and it works fine!